# Gradle is not place WebJar contents into the correct place in my Jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, webjars

I've got a basic Java application in which I would like to use WebJars. I use Gradle as my build system. I would like to use the WebJars for Bootstrap and JQuery so I can easily reference and update them in my Spring-Boot/ThymeLeaf application. The application is basically the one from the form tutorial located [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

As I understand it Gradle should place all the files from the WebJars into the META-INF folder in my Jar file. If I understand everything correctly the Spring-Boot resource handler will then load resource from `META-INF/` when I reference something in my html page that starts with `/webjars/`

Unfortunately this doesn't work (yet). Since I see in Tomcat's log output that the resource handler is correctly installed. I decided to check if the files are actually in my Jar file.

When I extract my Jar file the META-INF folder only has a file called `MANIFEST.MF` with some information about Spring Boot. There is a BootStrap-3.3.7.Jar and a JQuery-3.2-1.Jar file in `BOOT-INF/lib` but I don't think that is where they are supposed to end up. (Or am I wrong and is there error somewhere in the resource handler?).

How do I tell gradle to do the right thing with these files when I run `gradle build`?

My gradle.build file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()      
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")        
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-serving-web-content'
    version =  '0.0.1'
}

bootRun {
    addResources = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()  
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.webjars:jquery:3.2.1")
    compile("org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.7")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is doing the right thing as the jars should be packaged in `BOOT-INF/lib`. The root of each jar in `BOOT-INF/lib` is then added to the classpath from where each its webjar related content in `META-INF` content should be found.

I'd recommend asking another question that focuses on what your application's doing at runtime. As far as I can tell, everything's working as it should at build time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, gradle is doing the right thing. Seems someone else was confused about this which mislead me into believing gradle was at fault. It turns out its just Eclipse that's acting up. A build from console does everything correctly. :/. Probably a few reboots will get Eclipse back in order.

Comment: Yup rebooting Eclipse + refreshing the gradle project from Eclipse and then messing around with the launch configuration (which went wrong somehow) fixed it. :/